# How to check for negative values in text box in VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How to we check for negative values in a text box? I was only able to TryParse the text box so that there it will validate it if it's a numeric value:

```
If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtParts.Text, decParts) Then
    If decParts <= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Value must be a positive number!")
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Value must be numeric!")
    Return False
End If
```

Is it possible to check for negative values inside a TryParse method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `If` condition is basically saying if it *hasn't* successfully parsed it as a number. You want something like:

```
If Decimal.TryParse(txtParts.Text, decParts) Then
    If decParts <= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Value must be a positive number!")
        Return False
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Value must be numeric!")
    Return False
End If
```

Note the `Else` clause, and the inversion of the condition for `Decimal.TryParse`, and the return statement in the "not positive" part.