# Check for Negative Input in Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, input

I'm trying to validate a text box in a Windows Form Application. The text box takes any number (it's supposed to be a decimal but just whole numbers are accepted as well). I don't want the number to be negative but even after adding the if statement even if the number entered is negation the application still accepts it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
try
{
    //Different operations being done here that use the input from txtEnterTotal.Text 
}
catch
{
    decimal entertotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtEnterTotal.Text);
    if (entertotal <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number for the total field.", "Entry Error");
    }
}
```

I also tried this

```
catch
            {

                if (decimal.TryParse(txtEnterSubtotal.Text, out decimal value))
                {
                    if (value < 0)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number for the Subtotal field.", "Entry Error");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("thank you");
                    }
                }

            }
```

I found a similar question posted but it's in a different language I haven't learned yet but since it still asked about the same thing I tried some of the answers posted but I'm still having trouble.
Link: [How do you check if an input is a negative number in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805094/how-do-you-check-if-an-input-is-a-negative-number-in-vb)

Note: I want to do this using only using the try catch statement.

Comment: Consider using `Decimal.TryParse()` rather than using `try-catch`.  The latter generally shouldn't be used for normal program flow.  Besides, `Convert.ToDecimal` can in-turn throw exceptions whilst `xxx.TryParse()` doesn't

Comment: You're only checking for negatives *if there's an exception* - that is, in the `catch` code block of the `try/catch` statement - there may not be an exception, depending on what's happening in the `try` code block. In general, you should not need a `try/catch` there at all - see @MickyD's suggestion in the prior comment.

Comment: What is the problem with the code in that link, it uses .Net methods. In C#, you have the advantage that you can in-line the output variable: e.g. `if (decimal.TryParse(txtEnterTotal.Text, out decimal value)) { if (value < 0) { /* Negative value */ } } else { /* Not a valid value */ }`

Comment: I updated my code and have tried that as well but my application still accepts it and does all calculations despite the negative @Jimi

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal(txtEnterTotal.Text)` will throw an exception if `txtEnterTotal.Text` isn't a valid number. Probably don't want that in your `catch` block...

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the sample code is that you're doing `Convert.ToDecimal(txtEnterTotal.Text)` in the `catch` block, but this will throw an exception if `txtEnterTotal.Text` isn't a valid number, so the exception will now be unhandled.

Since you say you really want to use a `try/catch` to validate the textbox, then the basic pattern would be to try to convert the number in the `try` block, and if that fails, take action (that won't throw another exception) in the catch block.

For example:

```
private void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Here we perform the operation that might throw an exception
        decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtEnterSubtotal.Text);

        // If we get here, no exception was thrown
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you");
    }
    catch
    {
        // Since there was an exception, show a message and clear the textbox
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid, positive number");
        txtEnterSubtotal.Clear();
        txtEnterSubtotal.Focus();
    }
}
```

---

However, it's "expensive" to use `try/catch` for simple error handling (capturing the call stack has a cost), and it's also not their intended purpose (they should be used for *exceptional* events, not control of normal program flow).

This is a good time to learn about the [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) method that numeric types have. This method takes in a `string` to parse, and it sets an `out` parameter of the numeric type to the converted value if successful. The best part is that it returns a `bool` that indicates success, so we can use it in an `if` condition and take some action if the string parsing fails.

For example, you could have this code in your validation method which no longer requires a `try/catch`, since we do the validation with the `TryParse` instead:

```
private void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here we check if `TryParse` does NOT return true (note the exclamation mark), OR
    // if the converted number less than zero, where in either case we take some action
    if (!decimal.TryParse(txtEnterSubtotal.Text, out decimal value) ||
        value < 0)
    {
        // Show a message, then clear the textbox
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid, positive number");
        txtEnterSubtotal.Clear();
        txtEnterSubtotal.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to validate that your input is numeric and a decimal is to use some code like the following.  As the commenter, @MickyD suggested, `Decimal.TryParse` like this:

```
try
{
    //Different operations being done here that use the input from txtEnterTotal.Text 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // catch the exception and DO something with it.
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Error before try/parse: {0}", ex);
    //decimal entertotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtEnterTotal.Text);
    // old code ^^^^^^
    // new code 
    if (decimal.TryParse(txtEnterTotal.Text, out decimal entertotal))
    {
        if (entertotal <= decimal.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number for the total field.", "Entry Error");
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Failed to parse value: {0}", txtEnterTotal.Text));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is doing that code in the `catch` block? You have *Different operations being done here that use the input from txtEnterTotal.Text* up there, that's where the value entered in the TextBox is needed. The try/catch block should be removed, if not used for something else. But it's not about the validation of the TextBox.Text.

Comment: @Jimi agreed, there should be an exception instance there and we should do something with it.-- I was just working from the user's sample code and focusing on the `Decimal.Parse` issue at hand

Comment: @GlennFerrie I tried what you have and it works but when I click my Calculate button its accepted the first time and if I click it again then I get the message. It doesn't seem to catch it the first time

Comment: It's not about the *syntax* of the `catch` part, it's about the use of `.TryParse()`. The `try/catch` block is not needed anymore, that's what `TryParse()` is about.

Comment: I need to keep the try catch because that's what my textbook says to use otherwise I would've taken it out.  Even with the TryParse the application is still accepting the negative number. If I enter say -3 some how it changes it to 3.00 and continues @Jimi

Comment: If you want to keep the `try/catch` block, even if completely useless (unless, as mentioned, you're using it for something else), move that code into the `try` block.

Comment: @rythm500 _"that's what my textbook says to use"_ - I would get a different text book ;)